# How to make colorful liquid effect

Tags: adobe-photoshop, color, photoshop-effects, designers, graphic-styles

**This is a graphic from a Japanese artist called Mitsuo Katsui. I have been trying to figure out how I could emulate that liquid multi-color effect as well as giving it a slight glow as seen in the image. I have an idea on how to get the glow but, have no idea fo the other parts.**[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. What idea do you have for achieving the glow? What have you tried, or what has failed?

Comment: @BillyKerr To get the glow effect I know I can try to stack the layers and use the screen or lighten blending option. that might make it too bright so I can just turn down the opacity. it's the liquid color effect part that I no idea where to start

Comment: I think possibly applying a motion blur to a colourful gradient, followed by using the liquify filter might get you close.